# What's difference between private datacenter, and public cloud datacenter

Tags: cloud, datacenter

I'm very confused to understand what a cloud datacenter actually is.

In my experience, the main services of a data center are the following:

- Renting rackspace
- Rack colocation
- Server locating on rack
- Server leasing
- File storage
- ... etc

Cloud datacenters services are almost same. But what differences are there between them?

Answer (score 2):

*"Cloud"* is a marketing buzzword without relation to any specific technical aspect. As such, trying to define *"cloud"* in technical terms will inevitably fail. A "cloud" datacenter is simply a datacenter hosting *"cloud"* services (whatever that may mean in a specific case).

Answer (score 1):

yeha. and private cloud indicate the hosting your own cloud inside like openstack. public cloud is like  you are renting cloud services from third party like Amazon ec2.